How to apply rig properly so that the model moves with it?
I have a model that I want to animate. Now I first made a human meta rig and move all the bones within the mesh of my model, now I give all transform to my rig and Generate rig using rigify add on.
now I select the model and then the rig generate using rigify and parent them using automatic weights.
The problem comes when i try to move the rig in pose mode the model would not move with it, and some time when i try to parent the model and the rigify rig there is an error in the console that could not find solution for one or more bones.
so how can i make this work properly?

I made sure that there is no hidden bone present in the rig. I also tried to scale up my model and rig by 100 times as i saw in another question but that didnt worked.

Check you don't have any doubled verts or messed up geometry, that can often cause issues with auto-weights.

@Jakemoyo I did checked it after reading your comment and I had 17000 vertices removed but the automatic weight thing still doesnt works. Any other advise?

Are all of your objects joined together or is it separated, like Body, dress, collar, hair etc?

@Jakemoyo they are all joined .

I would try separating them into their own objects, anything thats not actually attached to the other should be a separate object.

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

@Jakemoyo I cant share the file actually. So you said about keeping the objects separated, so should I separate the clothes, hair, shoes from the model and then try to generate rig for it? can you explain this more briefly.

Yes, try separating each object, shirt, hair, shoes etc (doesn't have to be like each individual component, e.g don't separate laces from shoes, just "shoes" as their own object) and then try selecting all those objects, then your rig and parenting with automatic weights.

@Jakemoyo it is showing bone heat weighting error! when i tried to with all the objects seperately

I would look at the answers in this question. We've tried alot but if you can't share your blend file then it's hard to give a definitive answer.

@Jakemoyo Your separate method works fine now I retried it! thanks for the help man.

Separating the model into different objects shouldn't prevent you from parenting it to the rig, unless one of the mesh parts has an issue, I.E. too many polygons or overlapping vertices. But that's a different issue. I don't see the full feature Rigify rig in your screenshot, I also see a "female" mesh object that doesn't have any parent rig, and also you are posing the metarig, which isn't what you are supposed to use for posing. So are you sure you did generate the full feature rigify rig from the metarig, then parented the mesh objects to the rigify armature with automatic weights ?

@Lauloque yes, I first made the meta rig myself and then generate its armature using generate rig of rigify.

Where is the generated rig in your screenshot? What do you mean you made the metarig "yourself", you didn't use one provided by the rigify addon?

Most of the times in these scenarios, the problem is either doubled vertices, or multiple overlapping/non-manifold meshes in the same object. Automatic Weights works best when objects like shoes, clothes, hair, accessories are separated from each other.

